# Miscellaneous Star Looking character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query in which display values are returned. Some of these values that are coming back have an undesired apostrophe before the number value and some have a weird looking character before or after the number value. The display value is `varchar` and of varying length. Here a is an example of what I am talking about for the special character:

[image]

What is this character and how can I strip it out using the `replace()` function?

I tried the following and got the following result:

`substring(b.dsply_val, 5, 1)` gives the character in question

`UNICODE(SUBSTRING(b.dsply_val, 5, 1))` gives a result of 164

**UPDATE**

I am thinking of doing something like this, since results are inserted into a variable temp table:

```
, CASE WHEN unicode(substring(b.dsply_val, 1, 1)) = 164 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS POS_1
, CASE WHEN unicode(substring(b.dsply_val, 2, 1)) = 164 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS POS_2
, CASE WHEN unicode(substring(b.dsply_val, 3, 1)) = 164 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS POS_3
, CASE WHEN unicode(substring(b.dsply_val, 4, 1)) = 164 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS POS_4
, CASE WHEN unicode(substring(b.dsply_val, 5, 1)) = 164 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS POS_5
```

so if POS_1 = 1 then `where` clause it out in the final result set.

Comment: Locale/Unicode issue?

Comment: the character is a definition for **No number defined**. It looks somewhat like the character for "infinity" . the character is a symbol representation of `NULL`

Comment: Weird, I get that sometimes even after a number like 459*

Comment: Can you copy and paste the character? Or maybe post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASCII() in each and every character in the string, then update the question with the results so we can see the pattern.

Use the value returned by ASCII in the CHAR() function for replacement, i.e.

ASCII(bad character) returns x
REPLACE(string,CHAR(x),' ') - replaces that character with a space

or

REPLACE(string,CHAR(x),'*') - replaces that character with an asterisk

Also, contact whoever fills that field; see what they think they're putting in and how it should be displayed!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this will help but you might be able to get the unicode code for that character and then replace it.

```
-- Test variable
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(10) = '12345¶'

-- Get the code
SELECT UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@test, 6, 1))

-- Replace
SELECT REPLACE(@test, CHAR(182), 'Z')
```